# list of tuples to django queryset like object

Tags: python, django

I have a two lists something like the following:

```
month = ["Jan", "Feb" , ..., "Dec"]
temperature = [34, 35, .... , 29 ]
```

I can use above lists to make a list of tuple using zip

```
month_temperature  = list(zip(month, temperature))
# month_temperature = [ ("Jan", 34), ("Feb", 35), ..., ("Dec", 29)]
```

Consider an variable `mon_temp` (like a django queryset) very similar to `month_temperature` which lets me do this:

```
print(mon_temp[0].month) # Jan
print(mon_temp[0].temperature) # 34
```

Is it possible to create a variable like `mon_temp` ? Any Hints?

Comment: try namedtuple.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, Thank you, that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `namedtuple`

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> obj = namedtuple("Myobj", ["month", "temperature"])
>>> month_temperature  = list(map(lambda x: obj(*x), zip(month, temperature)))
>>> month_temperature[0].month
'Jan'
>>> month_temperature[0].temperature
34
```